# dojox.widget.Wizard not rendering buttons

Tags: asynchronous, dojo

I have a Wizard widget that I'm loading via async into a ContentPane. The first WizardPane shows up once it's loaded, but the buttons along the bottom do not.

Oddly, when I inspect the DOM for my page, the entries for the button regions are there.  They highlight the corresponding areas for buttons when I hover over them.  There's just nothing there!

This is happening on both Chrome and Firefox.

Any ideas as to what might be going on here?  Is there a trick to loading dojo widgets async that I might be missing?

Comment: dojo mailing list issue with more details and confirmation of the issue: http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/dojox-widget-Wizard-not-rendering-buttons-tp2526863p2526863.html;cid=1298038646521-267

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're simply missing the Wizard CSS. Add the following CSS

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojox/widget/Wizard/Wizard.css (or locally if you're loading Dojo locally).

http://jsfiddle.net/kfranqueiro/gLXHr/ updated and works

Comment: Well I'll be.  I knew I was uninitiated to the widget but that's certainly something I shoulda looked out for.  However, it didn't seem like you posted an actual updated version.  I just fixed and rebased the original though so that link should work now.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I'm not sure how to 'save' somebody elses fiddle, but thought it mangled the URL for you so you didn't have to?

Comment: Dojo doesn't (currently) support handling CSS imports automatically. It did in the 0.4 days, but support was removed due to complexities in the dependency management. Note: including a theme brings in all CSS for everything under the dijit namespace, and you can create custom CSS 'layers' with the build tool. Cujojs has done sone work trying to solve this for modern dojo, maybe check them out if you want an automatic solution.